# How to run php code once block is rendered?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, blocks, magento-2.1.7

I have a custom Block, and I want to run some code before this block will be rendered. How to achieve this?

I don't want to place my code inside Block method and run it from the template.

I don't want to place my code inside `__construct`, because it's no good for performance.

I think there is a maybe some event in Magento, that I can use for this.

I will be glad to any thoughts. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `_beforeToHtml` method of `Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock` in your block class, it call before rendering html of your block file.